# DataSnapshot manual creation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

DataSnapshot is always associated with firebase listeners, but I'm developing an app that queries the whole database on time basis, so I thought I can solve this problem by manually creating DataSnapshot instance but I can't find how to create. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = new DataSnapshot();
```

so I wanna know is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the the [snapshot reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot), you can see that there is no public constructor to create your own `DataSnapshot` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a new object using the new key like this:

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = new DataSnapshot();
```

Because `DataSnapshot class` does not have a no argument constructor. This [class](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html) provides a single constructor:

```
DataSnapshot(Firebase ref, com.firebase.client.snapshot.IndexedNode node)
```

Regarding Firebase:

> A DataSnapshot instance contains data from a Firebase Database location. Any time you read Database data, you receive the data as a DataSnapshot.

This is the only way in which you can use `DataSnapshot` with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot):

> A DataSnapshot instance contains data from a Firebase Database location. Any time you read Database data, you receive the data as a DataSnapshot.
>
> They are efficiently-generated immutable copies of the data at a Firebase Database location. They can't be modified and will never change.

Thus, you can't instantiate a DataSnapshot instance using a constructor.